# How do I fetch changes in a pull request to a repo?

Tags: git, version-control

I'm sorry if I'm going crazy. I basically have a repo, and someone made a pull request adding several file changes. I'd like to be able to pull those changes into my local machine so I can test some things out.

Found some links with several "success" stories and positive comments.. But I cannot get it to work for the life of me.

https://gist.github.com/piscisaureus/3342247
https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201407/fetching_github_pull_requests.html

I went to .git/config file and added fetch = +refs/pull/*/head:refs/remotes/origin/pr/* under origin. Then ran "git fetch origin". The links say the PRs are fetched, but from my command line I don't see ANYTHING at all. I just run "git fetch origin" and absolutely nothing appears. Any idea what it could be? maybe I'm using a newer version of git? I'm using version 2.23.0.windows.1

Here's my config file:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = placeholderUrl (don't worry.. I have the right one)
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    fetch = +refs/pull/*/head:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

Comment: ok, but that's if the change is merged right? I'm trying to get changes in a PR

Comment: A fetch doesn't merge the changes into your code. You need to do a `git merge origin/PR_XYZ` after the fetch to see the changes in your tree. Or you can view the changes in `gitk`

Comment: @EncryptedWatermelon I know, but see the links I added in the description. It says to only run git fetch origin, and then I should be able to at least see the list of PRs etc right?

Comment: Both links require you to fetch the PR then checkout the branch (PR). `git branch -va` will list the branches you fetched.

Comment: still don't see it. I see remotes/origin/HEAD and remotes/origin/master. I don't see any PR branches

Comment: the very onset of this issue is the fact that I'm unable to fetch the remote PR branches

Comment: @user6800688 here is how to get the PR branches: https://help.github.com/en/articles/checking-out-pull-requests-locally

Comment: Is your repo a github repo ? This PR fetching config is not compatible with all git hosters (like bitbucket)